# Linux API C++ Programming

Tags: c++, linux, winapi

I'm pretty green when it comes to the world of C++ programming, but I've recently dove headlong into it and am enjoying the learning process.

I've been curious about the Linux side of things though.  Throughout my career, I've mainly used Windows environments, but Linux exposure was still there to some degree.

My question is: Given that we have the Win32 API and visual studio on the Windows side, does there exist a Linux equivalent?  By 'Linux Equivalent' I mean an IDE similar to Visual Studio (for that intelli-sense auto-complete goodness) and an API structure similar to Win32? (for KDE/gnome for example)  Or given that Linux source code right down to the kernel is readily available, would it be best to look at that, and use function calls in my application appropriate to what I want to do?

I think I might be over-simplifying what would be a very ambitious task, but I'm curious about how things work 'under the hood'.  One of the best ways I learn is to do things for myself and see the results.  Towards that end, I plan on using Linux in a VM.  That way I at least have the option of snapshots and the ability to recover to a said snapshot in a worst-case scenario.

Comment: If you want os-level multiplatform code, you can use other libraries that support both platforms.

Comment: Vim + Grep + Ctags+ Cscope are the bare essentials for looking at Linux kernel code. Vim (depending who you ask) is better than Visual Studio (to the point that VScode has a VIm plugin). Grep, both in and out of vim, can do advanced searching. Ctags + cscope will jump to function definitions/calls which you can jump out of easily.

Comment: Also, maybe syscalls is what you're asking for with regard to API. Syscalls are the entry points from user programs into kernel functions. But you could modify your own kernel or create kernel device drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is the kernel, a linux based operating system is much more than that. To interact with linux itself you use system calls, then, on top of that you have the GUI, which can be either X server (the historical choice) or Wayland (the new standard). Both works slightly differently and have different APIs.

It is usually easier to work with a higher level framework, Like GTKmm or Qt if you want to reach the level of functionality in the win32 api. Those a slightly more expensive than win32, as they are abstraction layers on top of the actual graphical server, but the benefit is that they also work on windows (as abstraction on top of win32). I do prefer Qt to be honest, but GTK is a fine choice too (it is a c-library, but there exist a c++ port, GTKmm).

As for the IDE, I use Qt Creator, which is quite good. Other options include KDevelop, Eclipse, Visual studio (which has a linux version), ... and VIM if you are a purist.

Comment: [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) runs on Windows and Mac OS. There is no release for Linux. You might be confusing this with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which does run on *some* Linux distributions. That's not an IDE, though.

Comment: "Wayland (the new standard)" Sorry, there are so many things missing that it will take years until wayland can replace X at all. Currently wayland did not support multiple touch screens, is unable to calibrate touch and lots more with other inputs. Today wayland is minimal subset of functionality. I can't run wayland at all because more or less all which is not directly related to drive the graphic card is simply missing. They simply say, that moves to application level which means each app must reimplement what X was doing before. New standard?